# How to get parent jenkins job's name and build number from child job

Tags: jenkins, dsl

I have a Build Flow jenkins parent job with a DSL script that starts a Build Flow child job, also with a DSL script. Is there a way (groovy API) to get the parent job's name and build number in the child job?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Groovy script to get your Upstream Job details.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    
                        def cause = currentBuild.getBuildCauses('org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.BuildUpstreamCause')
                        if(cause.size() > 0) { // This is triggred by a upstream Job
                            def parentJobName = cause[0].upstreamProject
                            def parentBuildNumber = cause[0].upstreamBuild
                            echo "Parent JOb: $parentJobName"
                            echo "Parent Build Number: $parentBuildNumber"
                            
                        }
                    }
                   
               }
            }

        }
}
```

---

**Update**
You can get all the causes without passing the Class.

```
def cause = currentBuild.getBuildCauses()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The plugin used in my environment is com.cloudbees.plugins.flow. Looks like your plugin is different, so guess it does not apply to me.

Comment: @ThiagarajanHariharan if you don't want to check the exact type of cause you can get the Cause without passing the class. Check the update on the answer.

Comment: That did not work for me:

**println("currentBuild: ${currentBuild} ${currentBuild.getClass().getName()}")

ERROR: Failed to run DSL Script
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: currentBuild for class: Script1**